# Getting the 2nd element of a list

Tags: haskell

I have a function with this type:

```
calculator :: [Float] -> [Int] -> Float
```

and I need:

```
Helper :: [String] -> [[Int]] -> [Float] -> [(String, Float)]
```

Following problem is given:

I just want to take every 2nd element of the `[[Int]]`

e.g.: I have an given Int [[1,0], [2,0], [3,0]].

I want to  get the first element of each list in a list to put it into my calculator.

My idea was to concat the list of [Int].

e.g.:

[[1,0], [2,0], [3,0]].

```
concat [[1,0], [2,0], [3,0]] => [1,0,2,0,3,0]
```

I want this without the "0" values, due this is an indice which i dont need.

How can i remove every 2nd value in a list?

**Is that possible with a higher order function?**

Comment: (1) pattern matching could help you here (2) yes

Comment: In fact you want to take the first element of each sublist, so I suppose you could rephrase the subject of your question accordingly. Your problem can probably be solved by combining the [map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) and [head](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) library functions. Please remember that [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) is your friend in this endeavour.

Comment: I produced an answer to the question:

"How can i remove every 2nd value in a list?"

Comment: This is a perfect example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You are assuming the first step should be to use `concat`, then got stuck there. But if what you want is `[1,2,3]` from `[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]`, then skip `concat` and use `map head` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thinking goes like this: first, an empty list with every second value removed would be an empty list. Let's write that down:

```
withoutEverySecondValue [] = []
```

Now, if a list that consists of two values `x` and `y`, and then some tail `xs`, then to remove every second value from such list would mean (1) ignore `y`, (2) remove every second value from the tail `xs`, and (3) prepend `x` to the result of that. Let's write that down:

```
withoutEverySecondValue (x:y:xs) = x : withoutEverySecondValue xs
```

And that's it! Just add a type signature, and you're done!

```
withoutEverySecondValue :: [a] -> [a]
withoutEverySecondValue [] = []
withoutEverySecondValue (x:y:xs) = x : withoutEverySecondValue xs
```

There's one thing missing here though: what if a list is not empty, but also doesn't have two elements `x` and `y`? What should the result be then? I'll leave determining and writing that down as an exercise.

Answer (score -2):

This function will give you all but the 2nd element of a list:

```
allBut2nd :: [a] -> [a]
allBut2nd [] = []
allBut2nd list = head list : tail (tail list)
```